# Colors (from termcolor) not showing up when executing in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print some statements in different colors. When I try the following statement, it works fine:

```
    from termcolor import colored
    print ('!!!',colored('hello','red'), colored('world', 'green'),'!!!')
```

The output of the above command shows 'hello' in red and 'world' in green as expected. However, when I take an input before this command, the colors all go away. For example:

```
   filename = input(colored('\nEnter a file name: ','blue'))
   print ('!!!',colored('hello','red'), colored('world', 'green'),'!!!')
```

If I run the above statement, 'Enter a file name' shows up in Blue. As soon as I give an input, everything else is shown in black, even the 'hello world' string. Can anyone help me understand why an input command causes the colors to go away ?